# Average of range-value in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I webscraped the internet for products and reviews. Now I have the following value: '37.83-55.56'. This indicates the price-range of a certain product. How do I take the average of this range-value for this row?

Comment: you have problem parsing this thing? for average you need count and if this is only min/max value you cannot find average using that.
or i don't understand your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
import statistics
s = '37.83-55.56'
f = s.split("-")
f = [float(x) for x in f]
statistics.mean(f)
```